# Google Analytics API not connected using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-analytics

We are using Google Analytics API in PHP project.
But when I connect with API it gives the error below.
What am I doing wrong?

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to
>   Google_AuthHandler_Guzzle6AuthHandler::attachCredentials() must be
>   callable, string given, called in
>   /var/www/html/4lifesystem.com/analiytics/google-api-php-client-2.0.0/src/Google/Client.php
>   on line 370 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/4lifesystem.com/analiytics/google-api-php-client-2.0.0/src/Google/AuthHandler/Guzzle6AuthHandler.php
>   on line 30

---

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.0.0/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
$results = getResults($analytics, $profile);

printResults($results);

function initializeAnalytics()
{
    $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/lifesystem-c091337ab43b.json';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("lifesystem");
    $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    return $analytics;
}

function getFirstProfileId($analytics) {

    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

    if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
        ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $properties->getItems();
            $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

            $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
            ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

            if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
                $items = $profiles->getItems();
                return $items[0]->getId();
            } else {
                throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
    }
}

function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
    $profileId=79768194;
    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '7daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:sessions');
}

function printResults($results) {
    if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];

        print "First view (profile) found: $profileName\n";
        print "Total sessions: $sessions\n";
    } else {
        print "No results found.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a problem alright - are either of the files mentioned above your own, or are they part of a library?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: yes i m using google analytic class library. but when i connect with API it gives error.. If u want to show my code.. tell me i will post

Comment: Has it ever been working, or you are having problem to start using the API? What is the code you are using to connect? (Without exact IDs and credentials, of course.)